# UrlEncode is not encoding the + symbol and while decrypting Format Exception is coming up

Tags: c#, asp.net, formatexception

Let me explain the situation. In my code , I am encrypting the userid converted to string which is generated after a registration is done. The ecrypted string is passed as a url parameter as below.

```
 string ConfirmCode = string.Empty;
Common.Secure.Security mySec = new Common.Secure.Security();
ConfirmCode  = mySec.Encrypt(myMember.MemberID.ToString());

string EmailValidationLink = "<a  href=\'" + pageScheme + "://" + CurrentDomain.HostName + "/Contents/Common/" + "EN" + "/" + CurrentDomain.EmailValidationPage + "?ConfirmCode=" + **UrlEncode(ConfirmCode)** + "\'>Click here to validate your account.</a>";
```

And:

```
protected String UrlEncode(String text) 
{ 
  return HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlEncode(text); 
}
```

I am using the UrlEncode to pass the encrypted string, but the problem is if the encrypted text has a '+' symbol, while decryption I am getting a Format Exception , because this '+' symbol is taken as a ' ' space.

for example if the encrypted text is like 'S7+5tZzTm0k=' while fetching it, the + symbol is taken as 'S7 5tZzTm0k=' which is causing the format exception.

my encryption and decryption code is like below

```
public string Decrypt(string Text)
{
    if (!ENABLED) return Text;
    des.Key = hashmd5.ComputeHash(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(myKey));
    des.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
    ICryptoTransform desdencrypt = des.CreateDecryptor();
    Byte[] buff = Convert.FromBase64String(Text);
    return ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(desdencrypt.TransformFinalBlock(buff, 0, buff.Length));
}

public string Encrypt(string Text)
{
    if (!ENABLED) return Text;
    des.Key = hashmd5.ComputeHash(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(myKey));
    des.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
    ICryptoTransform desdencrypt = des.CreateEncryptor();
    ASCIIEncoding MyASCIIEncoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
    Byte[] buff = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Text);
    return Convert.ToBase64String(desdencrypt.TransformFinalBlock(buff, 0, buff.Length));
}
```

I have been googling about this and everybody suggests that using UrlEncode would solve the problem , but in my case even after using it has not solved the problem.

Please let me know how to go about this ?

```
if (Request.QueryString["ConfirmCode"] != null)
            { 
                bool isAccountSuspended;
                isAccountSuspended = AccountManagement.AcountManager.EmailValidationNote(HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString["ConfirmCode"]));

                if (!isAccountSuspended)
                {
                    lblMessage.Text = "Your account is already suspended. Please contact customer service.";
                    lblMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                }
                else
                {
                    lblMessage.Text = "Thank you for verifying your email address. We hope you’ll enjoy playing with us.";
                }
            }
```

Regards
Srividhya

Comment: Can you post the code for `UrlEncode`?

Comment: Does your `UrlEncode` method call `HttpUtility.UrlEncode`?  The `HttpUtility.Url*Decode*` method replaces '+' with ' ', but `HttpUtility.UrlEncode` shouldn't.

Comment: Indeed, are you using standard UrlEncode method of .NET Framework library? Because if not, you should.

Comment: The code for UrlEncode is already posted .. if you look at the string EmailValidationLink this line...

Comment: @drf No It is just UrlEncode and not HttpUrlEncode

Comment: @Vidya it's code usage, not the code of UrlEncode itself.

Comment: @Petr .. I did not understand your comment .. can you please eloborate

Comment: There are `HttpUtility.UrlEncode` and `HttpUtility.UrlDecode` static methods in standard .NET Framework library. You should use them for url encoding and decoding.

Comment: You are making a function call to your own `UrlEncode` method - what is in this method?

Comment: @Oded ... you mean to say what is in the UrlEncode method ???  protected String UrlEncode(String text)
        {
            return HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlEncode(text);
        }

Comment: Did you try `System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode` instead?

Comment: No I haven't ... Will try that and post if it is working fine

Comment: CAn you tell us what a value of `ConfirmCode` is and its matching `UrlEncode(ConfirmCode)`. In my tests UrlEncode is doing just what it should and Server.UrlEncode seems to just call HttpUtility.UrlEncode so I'm wondering if there is some other error in the logic of what is being passed in, etc.

Comment: @chris,@oded ... you guys are right ... the urlencode is passing it properly... but when I fetch the details from the query string and urldecode it... the text is having a space in the place of '+' symbol.

Comment: Here is the UrlEncode value = "?ConfirmCode=S7%2b5tZzTm0k%3d" and here is the value I get after UrlDecode "S7 5tZzTm0k="

Answer (score 1):

Required Using Directive: using System.Security.Cryptography;

```
Way to encrypt: HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Encrypt(Value));
```

Example: string value=HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Encrypt(Value));

```
Way to decrypt: Decrypt(HttpUtility.UrlDecode(value);

private string Encrypt(string clearText)
{
    string EncryptionKey = "MAKV2SPBNsdsI99212";
    byte[] clearBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(clearText);
    using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
    {
        Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 });
        encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
        encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                cs.Write(clearBytes, 0, clearBytes.Length);
                cs.Close();
            }
            clearText = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
        }
    }
    return clearText;
}
private string Decrypt(string cipherText)
{
    string EncryptionKey = "MAKV2SPBNsdsI99212";
    cipherText = cipherText.Replace(" ", "+");
    byte[] cipherBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);
    using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
    {
        Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 });
        encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
        encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                cs.Write(cipherBytes, 0, cipherBytes.Length);
                cs.Close();
            }
            cipherText = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(ms.ToArray());
        }
    }
    return cipherText;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply replace all occurrences of `+` with the [percent encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) - `%2B`.

```
UrlEncode(ConfirmCode).Replace("+", "%2B")
```

Comment: @PetrAbdulin - Should, yes. For some reason the `UrlEncode` call that the OP is using, doesn't.

Comment: That was my question.. why is the UrlEncode not doing it ?? if it has to do??

Answer (score 0):

OK, from all given data from you and other comments and answers, I've come to only one possible logical conclusion: **your url encoded string is decoded twice**. First decode of `S7%2B5tZzTm0k%3D` gives you `S7+5tZzTm0k=`, second decode gives you `S7 5tZzTm0k=`. It's only a matter of careful debug to detect place there string is url decoded twice.

P.S. As a way to verify that, *encode value twice*, it will be decoded correctly then. Twice encoded url value should be `S7%252B5tZzTm0k%253D`.

Answer (score 0):

On looking a bit I believe that `Request.QueryString` will give you a decoded version of what is in the querystring so that is giving you the version with the + and then you are effectively decoding it again which is where the mistake happens.

Change the line to the following

```
isAccountSuspended = AccountManagement.AcountManager.EmailValidationNote(Request.QueryString["ConfirmCode"]);
```

(ie remove the decode) and it should work.

Comment: I tried this but .. please see below ...  string ConfirmCode = Request.QueryString["ConfirmCode"];

                isAccountSuspended = AccountManagement.AcountManager.EmailValidationNote(ConfirmCode); but even then the problem still persists

Comment: What does `ConfirmCode` contains ?

Comment: What is the value you get out for `Request.QueryString["ConfirmCode"]`? If you are passing in `ConfirmCode=S7%2b5tZzTm0k%3d` then it should be what you want, I'd have thought. It is possible that you are getting the exception from a different place?

Comment: When I save the value for Request.QueryString["ConfirmCode"] to a string ConfirmCode , I am getting the value "S7 b5tZTm0k=".Please find the url "Contents/Common/EN/EmailValidationPage.aspx?ConfirmCode=S7+5tZzTm0k=" here in the url ... the ConfirmCode is getting passed properly

Comment: The Exception is coming here when it is trying to decrypt .if (!ENABLED) return Text;
            des.Key = hashmd5.ComputeHash(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(myKey));
            des.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
            ICryptoTransform desdencrypt = des.CreateDecryptor();
            Byte[] buff = Convert.FromBase64String(Text);
            return ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(desdencrypt.TransformFinalBlock(buff, 0, buff.Length));

Comment: in this line Byte[] buff = Convert.FromBase64String(Text); Here the text value is "S7 b5tZTm0k=" and it is causing the problem... If I manually just for testing edit the text and pass it with a + symbol is its working fine

Comment: `ConfirmCode=S7+5tZzTm0k=` in the url is not what it should be. However you have indicated elsewhere that `?ConfirmCode=S7%2b5tZzTm0k%3d` is the url. The latter is what the url should be correctly. The former is going to give you problems. I would then expect Querystring["ConfirmCode"] to be `S7+5tZzTm0k=` which should then be correct when you pass it to your Decode function...

Answer (score 0):

This is speculative, but I suspect you may be calling `UrlDecode` on the same string twice.

You indicated that the value in the URL is `ConfirmCode=S7%2b5tZzTm0k%3d`, which is correct (%2b is the correct encoding for '+').

If you decode this string once, you get `S7+b5tZTm0k=`, as expected.

If you decode *that* string, you will get `S7 b5tZTm0k=`, since '+' is decoded as ' '.  This is what you are seeing.

You may want to look through your decoding logic to ensure that the resultant string is only being decoded once.

Comment: When I save the value for Request.QueryString["ConfirmCode"] to a string ConfirmCode , I am getting the value "S7 b5tZTm0k=".Please find the url "Contents/Common/EN/EmailValidationPage.aspx?ConfirmCode=S7+5tZzTm0k=" here in the url ... the ConfirmCode is getting passed properly