# MVC5 Entity pk string, index and create OK but error 404 in edit, delete and details

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, http-status-code-404

I have [a string pk in oracle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8zy1.jpg) in a table named `REGISTROS`. I have an ASP.NET MVC project and use Entity Framework.

I build a `RegistrosController` with scaffold. I can list and create but I can't edit, details or delete. Would you help me please? The variable which is id-registros:

[image: the variables]

The action method which received the variable:

[image: the action method]

The route config file:

[image: Route config]

Comment: Please, post and properly format your code **as text** - don't just show us screenshots of your code, that's highly annoying and not good practice on SO ....

Comment: Excuse me, marc_s. It was my first post.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple.

1. Because your link url looks like `/Registros/Edit/3-14/12/19`

   MVC URL uses `/` as route (area , controller , action).

   If ID_REGISTRO is string type number

   why not use `-` split string?

   ***Maybe it is too late to consider encoding rules of your pk.***
2. My suggestion is AES Encrypt/Decrypt your pk string.

   `@Html.ActionLink("Editor" , "Edit" , new { id = EncryptHelper.EncryptString( "3-14/12/19") })`

Here is AES Encrypt/Decrypt Helper

```
public class EncryptHelper
    {
        private static string KeyVal = "put your random string here";
        private static string IvVal = "put your random string here";

        public static string EncryptString(string text)
        {

            using (AesCryptoServiceProvider aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                aes.Key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(KeyVal);
                aes.IV = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(IvVal);
                // Encrypt the string to an array of bytes.
                byte[] encrypted = EncryptString(text, aes.Key, aes.IV);

                return WebUtility.UrlEncode(Convert.ToBase64String(encrypted));
            }
        }

        public static string DecryptString(string base64Str)
        {

            base64Str = WebUtility.UrlDecode(base64Str);
            base64Str = base64Str.Replace(" ", "+");
            using (AesCryptoServiceProvider aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                aes.Key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(KeyVal);
                aes.IV = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(IvVal);

                return DecryptString(
                    Convert.FromBase64String(base64Str), aes.Key, aes.IV);
            }
        }


        static byte[] EncryptString(string plainText, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
        {
            if (plainText == null || plainText.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("plainText");
            if (Key == null || Key.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
            if (IV == null || IV.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("IV");
            byte[] encrypted;

            using (AesCryptoServiceProvider aesAlg = new AesCryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                aesAlg.Key = Key;
                aesAlg.IV = IV;

                ICryptoTransform encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);

                using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        using (StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
                        {
                            swEncrypt.Write(plainText);
                        }
                        encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray();
                    }
                }
            }

            return encrypted;
        }

        static string DecryptString(byte[] cipherText, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
        {
            if (cipherText == null || cipherText.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("cipherText");
            if (Key == null || Key.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
            if (IV == null || IV.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("IV");

            string plaintext = null;
            using (AesCryptoServiceProvider aesAlg = new AesCryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                aesAlg.Key = Key;
                aesAlg.IV = IV;

                ICryptoTransform decryptor = aesAlg.CreateDecryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);

                using (MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(cipherText))
                {
                    using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                    {
                        using (StreamReader srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))
                        {
                            plaintext = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
                        }
                    }
                }

            }

            return plaintext;
        }
    }
```

3.After encrypt string will be 
`/Registros/Edit/ZF%252F4Q5oa2zXyzUtDSH33sA%253D%253D`

4. You may got IIS 404.11 Error. go to IIS Admin  > MIME > Check Double escape On.
5. By the way ! AES Dncrypt with url may got error. becuase `+` and `space` must be replaced.you may check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/10025926/7016640

6 days ago. hope this help !